# JSONP works with XML?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I have this URL that is in XML: [cdn.florianbussmann.de/stackoverflow/21140602_catalog.xml](http://cdn.florianbussmann.de/stackoverflow/21140602_catalog.xml)

I was using xmlHttprequest to work with this data in my javascript, but because of the same origin policy. I have to use JSONP. I found some examples, right now I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"http://cdn.florianbussmann.de/stackoverflow/21140602_catalog.xml",
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        success:function(json){

            alert("Success");
        },
             error:function(){
                 alert("Error");
        },
    });
```

I always get an error, is it because I can not convert this XML page to JSONP?

Comment: JSONP doesn't magically allow you to use arbitrary JSON/XML data in your page.  It's something the server needs to support, not just the client.  JSONP works by appending a `<script>` tag to your head with the `src` set to the request.  The file loaded usually contains a call to the function specified by a `callback` parameter with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONP isn't something you can request from a site that is not prepared to respond properly.  In other words, whoever is in control of the target site must provide a JSONP response API.